# RTK Query get object inside result

Tags: redux-toolkit, react-query, rtk-query

my getMovies returns object data but what i need is data.result inside data. How can I directly get data.result?

My API: https://movie-flask.c3-na.altogic.com/movies

My code:

```
export const movieApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'movieApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'https://movie-flask.c3-na.altogic.com/'
    }),
    tagTypes: [],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getMovies: builder.query({
            query: () => "movies",
        })
    }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components
export const { useGetMoviesQuery } = movieApi
```

I have tried

```
getMovies: builder.query({
   query: () => "movies",
}).result
```

It does not work.

Below is how i call useGetMoviesQuery

```
const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetMoviesQuery();

{data && data.result && data.result.map((item, i) => (
    <Text key={i}>
         {item.name}
    </Text>
))}
```

I want to get rid of data.result and directly want to call it with data.map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [transformResponse](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-query-responses-with-transformresponse):

```js
getMovies: builder.query({
    query: () => 'movies',
    transformResponse: response => {
        return response.result
    },
})
```